# VueCLI + Webpack : I need a separate css file from a single scss

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

I'm building an app with VueCLI and webpack.
My app has the usual main main.js with vue components and scss assets compiling as expected to global .js and .css files.

But I also need to have a single example.scss file in my /src directory that compiles to a separate example.css file in a specific directory.

Here's my /src directory structure

/src
- /assets
-- /scss
--- index.scss
--- _import1.scss
--- _import2.scss
**--- example.scss**
- /components
-- ... my vue components sit here
- main.js
- App.vue

What I want in the /dist directory:

/dist
- /css
-- index.hash.css
**-- example.hash.css**
- /js
-- index.hash.js
- index.html

How can I configure the vue.config.js file, with a custom webpack config (https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#simple-configuration), to enable the export of the separate example.css file ?

thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can add another entry point which will build it separately\

**vue.config.js**

```
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.entry('example')
      .add('./src/example.scss')
      .end()
  }
```